# How can I simulate touch screen clicks on Android phone from my PC?

Tags: android

I am trying to control android phone touch screen, It's not have keypad available .

Is there  any known tool that can send command to Android touch screen  as if the user touch the screen ?

Thanks,
Koby

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try the solution presented here: http://www.taranfx.com/remotely-control-android-phone-vnc-server

Comment: Thanks, Method 2 looks like what I am searching

Answer (score 3):

You could try [Android Monkey](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/monkey.html) which was built for stress testing application UI